# Hibernate 6 issues with table name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hana, hibernate-6.x

Recently upgraded to Spring boot 3 and implicitly yo hibernate 6.
One issue I am facing is that depending on the annotations on an Entity class, the table name is parsed differently.

For example I have this entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Folder.TABLE_NAME)
@SecondaryTable(name = RelationView.TABLE_NAME, pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NODE"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Folder extends Entity<Folder, Integer> {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_NO_QUOTES = "com.proj.db::base.folder";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "`" + TABLE_NAME_NO_QUOTES + "`";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ENTITY_SEQUENCE")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "ENTITY_SEQUENCE",
            strategy = ...SequenceStyleGenerator")
    private Integer folderId;
...other fields
```

When I try to start up the application it fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(com.backend.model.Folder) `sqmMultiTableMutationStrategy` interpretation
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(com.backend.model.Folder) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation

    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.execute(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 54 more
    Suppressed: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse object name: "com.proj.db::base.folder"
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.QualifiedNameParser.parse(QualifiedNameParser.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.QualifiedNameParser.parse(QualifiedNameParser.java:199)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.temptable.TemporaryTable.<init>(TemporaryTable.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.temptable.TemporaryTable.createEntityTable(TemporaryTable.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect.getFallbackSqmInsertStrategy(H2Dialect.java:693)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.SqmMultiTableMutationStrategyProviderStandard.createInsertStrategy(SqmMultiTableMutationStrategyProviderStandard.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.interpretSqmMultiTableInsertStrategy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4807)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lambda$prepareMappingModel$17(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4659)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:106)
        ... 64 more
```

If I remove the @GeneratedValue, @GenericGenerator and anything related to the @SecondaryTable annotation everything works fine.
I also have the physical naming strategy set up in my application.yaml.

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

From what I can tell looking in the hibernate code the issue comes from org.hibernate.dialect.temptable.TemporaryTable constructor, which from version 6.1.4 has changed the way it parses the table name to use QualifiedNameParser which is incompatible with our naming convention (we use a Hana database) and also seems to ignore the physical naming strategy property.

Has anyone encountered anything similar? Am I missing something? Is there a new property that I have missed?

Comment: Have you tried asking on a Hibernate forum? If the behavior has changed and you can identify the code that changed, and you think this is a bug, you can file a report on the [Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse).  Also [this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10174?search_id=683408d3-7d41-4ce0-baaa-7a8979510df8)?